# Specified data directory does not exist - but it does...

Tags: api, bitcoin-cli

anyone ever had a similar issue where the directory exists but bitcoin-cli isn't recognizing it? Perhaps this is related to me setting the folder up as a symlink to my external HDD?

Thank you!
aaronson

```
-Mac-mini:~ $ bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 1
Error reading configuration file: specified data directory "/Users/---/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin" does not exist.
-Mac-mini:~ $ cd /Users/---/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin
-Mac-mini:Bitcoin $ ls
banlist.dat bitcoind.pid    chainstate  db.log      peers.dat
bitcoin.conf    blocks      database    debug.log   wallet.dat
```

Comment: Do not use backslash and space symbols in folder name

Comment: @aaronson If that was the solution, can either of you turn it into an answer so it can be marked accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use backslash and space symbols in folder name

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue, too, and removing spaces (escaped or otherwise) appears to have solved the issue.

Like the OP, I was using a path containing `Application\ Support`.

`$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Bitcoin` is the MacOS default, though, so hopefully most people won't need to set that explicitly.

Comment: Curiously, though, `datadir` seems to be autogenerated in my `bitcoin.conf` file every time I run `bitcoind`. 

That leads to issues on future runs whenever I'm using the default path, which contains `Application Support`